# Is strlen(__FILE__) evaluated at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11

Is `strlen(__FILE__)` evaluated at compile time -- assuming I'm using a recent compiler (GCC, Clang, MSVC)?

Comment: Look at the generated code.

Comment: You can probably use `sizeof(__FILE__) - 1`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Clang and gcc are both able to compute this at compile-time thanks to [constant-folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) optimization passes, but this is nowhere enforced in the C++ standard.

Using `sizeof` [could ensure](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a66adaef88d52d5) that this is computed at compile-time.

Comment: `sizeof(__FILE__) - 1` won't yield the same result as `strlen(__FILE__)` if `__FILE__` contains a null character. In practice, that will never happen.

Comment: @KeithThompson Why would it not yield the same result if it has a null character?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Why would it? `strlen` stops at the first null character, `sizeof` does not.

Comment: @hvd But that's why we do `- 1` to `sizeof`. It gives the same result [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/caf8358d009d7c51).

Comment: @0x499602D2: That's because `__FILE__`, in that particular implementation (and probably every implementation) does not have embedded null characters. If it did, the result would be different. For example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f8828c55231a9e5

Comment: @0x499602D2: For example, `sizeof "foo\0bar" == 8`, but `strlen("foo\0bar") == 3`. In practice, Unix-like systems explicitly forbid null characters in file names, and Windows is even more strict. (But I've found that a source file name containing a newline breaks gcc's expansion of `__FILE__`.)

Comment: I suggest updating your answer to show the use of `sizeof __FILE__ - 1`.

Comment: @KeithThompson "In practice, Unix-like systems explicitly forbid null characters in file names" -- but not in `#line` directives. Nevertheless, GCC, clang and Intel all make `__FILE__` a single byte (`""`) after `#line 1 "\0"`.

Comment: @hvd: And you can make your error messages beep by using `#line __LINE__ "\a.c"`. (To anyone else reading this: *never do this*.)

Answer (score 0):

No, because strlen is not defined by the standard as a constexpr function

Comment: At least one of the OP's listed compilers does calculate string lengths at compile time. It's not required, and I don't know about the other compilers, but it's a perfectly valid and sensible optimisation.